why is a matrix calculation for cosine similarity much slower than a loop of vector calculations?
I am trying to optimize my cosine similarity calculations to be as efficient as possible. At first I was calculating the vectors, storing said vectors in a matrix and finally calling each row to perform the calculation. While trying to optimize, I thought it might be more efficient to perform the calculation across the entire matrix per vector (removing the inner for loop). Without jit, it worked well seeing a reduction in time required to process. Though jit across each vector was still faster. When I applied jit to the matrix calculation, the time to process ballooned making it the least efficient.
Does anyone know why this happens?
modules
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from timeit import default_timer as timer

calculation code
# @jit(nopython=True)
def cosine_sim_matrix(matrix, vector):
    dot_product = np.dot(matrix, vector)
    magnitude_a = np.sqrt((matrix ** 2).sum(axis=1))
    magnitude_b = np.sqrt((vector ** 2).sum())
    similarity_score = dot_product / (magnitude_a * magnitude_b)
    similarity_score[similarity_score > 1] = 1
    similarity_score[similarity_score < -1] = -1
    return similarity_score

# @jit(nopython=True)
def cosine_sim_vector(vector_1, vector_2):
    dot_product = np.dot(vector_1, vector_2)
    magnitude_a = np.sqrt((vector_1** 2).sum())
    magnitude_b = np.sqrt((vector_2 ** 2).sum())
    similarity_score = dot_product / (magnitude_a * magnitude_b)
    if similarity_score > 1:
        similarity_score = 1.0
    elif similarity_score < -1:
        similarity_score = -1.0 
    return similarity_score

test
mymatrix = np.random.rand(10000,1000)

# timing matrix calculations
start = timer()
for idx in range(mymatrix.shape[0]):
    vec = mymatrix[idx,:]
    cosine_sim_matrix(mymatrix, vec)
end = timer()
print(f"process time, matrix={end-start}")

# timing vector calculations
start = timer()
for idx in range(mymatrix.shape[0]):
    vec = mymatrix[idx,:]
    for idx2 in range(mymatrix.shape[0]):
        vec2 = mymatrix[idx2,:]
        cosine_sim_vector(vec, vec2)
end = timer()
print(f"process time, vector={end-start}")

results
# no jit
process time, matrix=348.5313815
process time, vector=839.2151422999999

# with jit
process time, matrix=883.4681065999998
process time, vector=275.0485957000001

I thought that maybe it had to do with the matrix ** 2 and opted to change to np.linalg.norm but the current numba version does not support axis calculations.
edit:
I have found this post about improving numba matrix cosine calculations. The code here is very efficient, opting for multiple for loops to produce the dot product and magnitudes.
here is the speed using this code
process time, no parallel, matrix=109.96504489999916
process time, w/ parallel, matrix=21.85965199999964 

my question though has more to do with the code in question.

I'm not sure why changing from your cosine_sim_vector to cosine_sim_matrix results in such a large slowdown with numba.
Though you should note that you are timing the compilation time, and that typically you would also include the for loops that call your functions within a njit decorated function as they can also be compiled.
You can write this entirely in numpy (compatible with numba apart from the norm calculation that needs rewriting), which is significantly faster than your code for the given matrix size:
def cosine_similarity(matrix):
    matrix_norm = np.linalg.norm(matrix, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    ratio = matrix / matrix_norm
    out = ratio.dot(ratio.T)
    out[out > 1.] = 1.
    out[out < -1.] = -1.
    return out

%timeit cosine_similarity(mymatrix)

results in:
644 ms ± 17.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

